# Can I use fast traineddata set in Java?

Tags: java, performance, tesseract

On windows 7,I am trying to use Fast Traineddata files in my java project. But I am getting Invalid Memory access when using it even after setting datapath.

I have tried to use best data files but it also gives same error. Default data files are working but it is huge file so I was going for fast files.

```
    Tesseract tess = new Tesseract();

    tess.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\U6070534\\Downloads\\tes4j\\tessdata");
    tess.setLanguage("eng");

    String inputFilePath = "C:\\Users\\U6070534\\IdeaProjects\\ocrsample\\screenshot\\craft0.png";
        try {
            textpath.add(tess.doOCR(new File(inputFilePath)));
        } catch (TesseractException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:470)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:404)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getOCRText(Tesseract.java:437)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:292)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:213)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:197)
at OcrReader.main(OcrReader.java:25)
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Google for your error message: it found this - https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j/issues/34

Comment: I checked the thread. It is related to Mac and it is not similar to mine

Comment: Is that the correct path? Looks like it's missing a letter in `tes4j`. Try to verify the path using `File.exists` method.

Comment: It's correct path. I named my folder as tes4j instead of tess4j, also the same code is working if I am using default traineddata